# Создание видеоконференции

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asp.net-core, webrtc

Подскажите, как создать видео+аудиострим p2p, а так же через сервер?
Я почитал по WebRTC и не рахобрался, какой код мне нужно написать, что б в самом простом случае запустить сайт на телефоне и на компьютере и при этом коммуницировать?

Comment: Даёшь HELLO WORLD по p2p !

Comment: Вот демо - https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc
Но там не так уж и мало кода

Comment: Возможно, что [этот проект](https://github.com/maks1mp/video-chat-webrtc) на react + express поможет разобраться